# Real-time updating framework

Tags: java, c++, excel, publish-subscribe

I am trying to implement a real-time updating framework, where changing input data automatically leads to recalculating all dependent results. So I need a kind of subscription mechanism, but a clever one, as I have to handle enormous amounts of data. I like to think about the mechanism as a "calculation tree" or directed graph, with the nodes representing the results, and the edges representing the functions.

Something similar must have been implemented in MS Excel, with the cells being the nodes, but Excel will not fulfill my needs as it is not able to handle large amounts of data, and is not flexible enough.

While in principle I want to be able to browse through the complete calculation tree (including all results in the complete depth of the tree), I know that this could mean storing several Terabytes of data. So I need to be able to forget or skip nodes if the computer runs out of memory, and then recalculate them as needed. And not to forget: while programming the (short!) functions, I don't want to be bothered with endless technical subscribe stuff (ideally this should be taken care of automatically in the framework).

Do you think it's doable, and if so, how would you attack it? Do you know of any component / library which one could use for this type of things? I have thought about publish/subscribe mechanisms and message brokers, but fear they are going to slow down my calculations.

Thx in advance for your responses!

Calle

Comment: I would treat is as a directed graph just as you suggested. In case of data changing in any of the nodes just traverse the graph starting in that node. Each time you visit a node, redo the calculations if needed.

Comment: how do you represent "all dependent results"? Are they a classes?

Comment: What kind of real-time performance and target platform are you aiming at? Are there any actual deadlines involved or is it "just" about fast live updates? Also, will you have to look at most of the results simultaneously or only a few.

Comment: @piotrus: A "result" is first and foremost a double. But it could in principle also be represented as a simple instantiated class (with the result as property).

Comment: @MikeMB: Platform will probably be Windows, but a platform-independent solution would be nice. No actual deadlines, only fast updates, avoiding unnecessary calculations. I will typically look at a grid of results (maybe up to 1000), but browsing the complete tree with input data will involve only relatively few nodes.

Comment: Depending on how your data tree is going to look like, it MIGHT be more efficient, if you don't actively push the update to all nodes but let the nodes, which are currently displayed request a new update whenever an input is changed. When you talk about several terabytes do you mean that you will have some trillion nodes or will each node contain a big amount of data? I'm asking, because it obviously will make a big difference whether the full graph representation will fit into the main memory or not.

Comment: How large is "enormous" data? How much of the data is dependent on the inputs? Modern computers can do quite a lot of calculations in a second, so it may be simpler to keep a relatively basic dataformat, and "brute-force it"...

Comment: @MikeMB: I think there will be a lot of nodes with just a few doubles on each - otherwise the "only update if input nodes change" will be less efficient.

Comment: @Mats Petersson: Almost all of the computed data is dependent on its inputs, which may be computed nodes themselves. What do you mean by "brute-forcing" it?

Comment: Basically, just recalculate everything. If all the calculations are changing anyway, you will need to. On the other hand, you probably still need to have a dependency tree to determine which nosed to calculate first, so perhaps a silly ide.

Comment: Ok, once more: From your answers I deduce that you are talking about handling serveral hundret billion computation nodes (Some TB of data devided by some 10 bytes of data per node means ~10^11 nodes) and you want to handle that on a "normal" workstation with a few Gigabytes of main memory. Is that correct? In this case we are talking about advanced database programming because you have to store most of your computation tree layout (not to mention the data) on your hard drive. Sorry, but thats outside my field of experience.

Comment: Where do these computation formulas come from anyway? Is there some regularity one can exploit?

Comment: @MikeMB: The data result as a Cartesian product of several dimensions, e.g., a date dimension, a scenario dimension, etc. And of course a TB of RAM sounds much, but may be affordable in a couple of years. But managing memory consumption by an adaptive forget/recalc mechanism is actually part of my vision, even if my computer has only 36GB of RAM - I do not think it is strictly _necessary_ to use a database.

Comment: @user3366312 recalculating the data is not a problem, but I was afraid that the representation of your network might not fit into the main memory and that is something you cannot simply recalculate. However, big cartesian products should not pose a problem, because then you just need a node representing the catesian product, which caches the inputs and  calculates the necessary values when required.